# Gson why does my deserialization not work?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to make a java program that will need to work with json, I have choose gson as my library to handle managing JSON

But when I try to deserialize my json the `messagereturn.text` value and the `messagereturn.extra.text` value both get set as null, I have tried to fix this but I am unable to.

An example of the json that i am trying to deserialize is

```json
{
    "text":"",
    "extra":[{
        "text":"eee joined the game",
        "color":"yellow"
    }]
}
```

And this is how I am calling gson

```java
Message messagepacket = event.<ServerChatPacket>getPacket().getMessage();
//this gets the json data
messagereturn messagereturn =  gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(messagepacket), messagereturn.class);
System.out.println(messagereturn.returnmethod());
```

Here is the class I am trying to deserialize too

```java
public class messagereturn {
    String text;
        
    public class extra{
        String text;
    }
    
    public String returnmethod() {
        extra extra = new extra();
        return text + extra.text;
    }
}
```

Thank you, if there is any more informaton needed let me know, thanks

Comment: @J.F. I figured it out thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem understanding your JSON (and creating the Java classes by the way). These marks `[]` means that is a list.

So you have an object with atributes `text`, type `String` and `extra`, type `List<Object>`.

This list contains another object (note that the object is defined by `{}` and list by `[]`).

The object into the list has another two attributes: `text` and `color` both with primitive types; `String`.

So your java class should be like this:

```java
public class Messagereturn {

    private String text;
    private List<Extra> extra;
    
    //getters and setters and other methods
    
}
```

And the class `Extra`:

```java
public class Extra {

    private String text;
    private String color;
    
    //getters and setters
}
```

With this data model you can call your `Gson` with these structure.

Also, you don't need to call `returnMethod` to create `Extra` object, it is created by `Gson`.

Using this line of code:

```java
Messagereturn mr = new Gson().fromJson(txt, Messagereturn.class);
```

And your JSON example, this is the value stored when run in debug mode:

[image: java object]

As you can see, tha values from JSON has been created and loaded into memory.